# How to print all MAC addresses of devices interacting with wifis in my area to stdout

Tags: wifi, stdout, tcpdump, mac-address, wireshark

How do I configure a tool like wireshark, kismet, tcpdump to passively listen to wifi traffic?

How do I get one of these tools to print these MAC addresses to stdout? I want just one MAC address per line. I want them to print each MAC address they detect, I don't care whether they detected that certain address before.

Comment: In your area or on your network?  The tools you mention are network tools, not wifi spying tools.  Also show us what you did so far and didn't work.  The point of this site is to help you, not to get your work done by others.

Comment: Passively listening to network traffic can be attained by setting your NIC to promiscuous mode. Just google the term and you will find how to do this, but I highly doubt you want this, unless you will dedicate a machine to sit, do nothing but listen to wi-fi traffic, with no other network connectivity. Look into using `arp` or `nmap`. Both of them provide MAC addresses as well as associated IP addresses. It is up to you to format the output to your desire

Comment: @julie 1. I want to sniff one network in particular, but I don't want to be logged in to that network, so I wouldn't consider it "my network". It's a wifi using 802.1x authentication.
2. I don't understand how to configure and use the tools I mentioned. I also could not find a tutorial explaining it to me in a way I am able to understand it.

Comment: @MelBurslan I want to do exactly that, actually.

Comment: At best, all you'll be able to get are packets on a single wifi channel at a time.  I understand that your point is to spy or hack your neighbors but doing so efficiently might require multiple wifi adapters.

Comment: Ok, getting packets on a single wifi network would suffice.

Comment: !!NOT!! Single wifi network. SINGLE CHANNEL. As you might have noticed, when you go to the wifi setup of any home router, you will see 15 channels and it asks you to select one of them. Whichever channel you choose, is the channel, on which you can  snoop the packets.  Also, please understand, unauthorized access to others' data in any way, shape or form is a crime punishable by law. Just to let you know what you are getting yourself into.

Comment: @MelBursian Let's not defamate anyone. Spilot didn't say anything about illegal activities. We should assume he's acting within the law. I personally see no reason why I can't listen to unencrypted MAC addresses being broadcasted into my home/office if I want to. I have wifi analysing software that supports this as well that I use professionally. We don't know what the situation with spilot is.

Comment: Just to clarify things: I'm implementing a widget on a website of a local student group, displaying whether the group's room is open or not. For this purpose, the MAC addresses being sniffed will be compared to a list of MAC addresses of devices of people having a key for the room in concern. If the intersection of these sets should not be empty, a banner saying "the room is open" will be displayed on the web. This is nowhere near illegal activity at all.

Answer (score 3):

Listen on a wifi network that you are connected to or any network?

#### Connected network with tcpdump

```
$ tcpdump -le | egrep -o '([0-9A-Fa-f]{2}[:-]){5}([0-9A-Fa-f]{2})'
```

#### Not connected with aircrack-ng

For watching all wifi traffic, even on different SSIDs you'll need something like `aircrack-ng's airodump-ng`. I'm not setup to use it right now, so I can't help with formatting it's output as I did with tcpdump. It can save output to various file formats that perhaps you can process with grep in the same way.

The console output looks like this:

[image: ss #1]

#### airodump-ng documentation

- https://www.aircrack-ng.org/doku.php?id=airodump-ng